# Save Django Model Form and refresh after selecting a Foreign Key Object

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-forms

I have the following models:

```
class Pic(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    img = ImageField(upload_to='images/', default=None, null=True, blank=True)

class InputTest(models.Model):
    pic_id = models.ForeignKey(Pic, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image_field_crop = CropperImageField(upload_to='images/', default=None, null=True, blank=True)
```

When adding a new InputTest object, the admin selects a PicID Object (foreign key) from the existing ones. I want right after selecting it, the object to save and refresh.

For example:

- When adding a new **InputTest** object,  I select **PIC#1** as foreign key. The program will run this overwritted method:

  ```
  def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False, using=None, update_fields=None):
      super(InputTest, self).save(force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)
      self.image_field_crop = self.pic_id.img
      super(InputTest, self).save(force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)
  ```
- Then when the pages refreshes, the image_field_crop is **auto-completed** with the **PIC#1.img** and I can use it in CropperJS (using CropperImageField)

Is it possible to do this? To auto-save the object and refresh the page right after selecting the pic_id when adding a new InputTest.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can use below save method in InputTest model
after you select a pic_id in InputTest admin and select save button image_field_crop filed filled automatically

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.image_field_crop = self.pic_id.img
        super(InputTest, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

I hope it helps you